# Python requests/urllib2 not returning full data after some time whereas browser does - facebook graph API events search

Tags: python-2.7, facebook-graph-api, python-requests, urllib2, facebook-events

I am requesting URL to get the public events:

```
https://graph.facebook.com/v2.4/search?access_token={<access_token>}&q=Austin&type=event&pretty=1&fields=id,name&limit=1000
```

When I first hit the url the json data length is coming correct Both in browser and terminal.

[image]

But after some time(~2 hrs) of testing the data length reduces to 298 from 373...
I thought requests might be causing some problem so I tried urllib2 also.. but the result is again the same.

[image]

And when I tried after 5-6 hours the result is again different(*total events are again 373, which is the desired result*)

[image]

I thought it may be because of some **RATE LIMITS** and I tried searching for it but didn't find satisfactory answers so finally posting here :)

**I'll appreciate any idea of why this might be happening, 'cuz it would really be a step towards understanding and resolving this issue.**

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Can you elaborate on "after some time of testing the data length reduces"?  How long is "some time"? How much is the data reduced?

Comment: @mrnick around 2 hours... and length of key "data" is reduced to 298 from 373 as shown in terminal and browser snapshots.